# Clearing session in jsp

Tags: session, jsp-tags

i have developed a web appilcation using jsp and when user try to logout, session is not clearing even though i have used `session.invalidate()` and `session.removeAttribute("username"); session.removeAttribute("type");` When i press back button of browser it redirects to previous page of the user.

my code for logout is

```
<%
  session.removeAttribute("username");
  session.removeAttribute("type");
  session.removeAttribute("Data");
  session.invalidate();
  response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); 
%>
```

thanks in advance.....